# Microsoft Form - If Checkbox Cell Value Greater Than

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word

First post on this forum - I have a fillable form which I would like to do the following.

There are two check boxes, (Legacy form item), labelled H and N, depending on which one is selected the value of another input box (Legacy form item) should be equal to or greater than a value. E.G if N is selected, the input cell should be greater than 0.5 if H is selected the cell should be equal to or greater than 0.5.

Can anyone impart any wisdom on this one, I would then set it to run a check once the user has input the value, based on the checkbox option and value input into the cell.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 objects and you need to react on any change. So I'd put something like this into the code section of the form:

```
Private Sub cbN_Click()   ' name of checkbox N is cbN
     proc_chg
End Sub

Private Sub cbH_Click()
     proc_chg
End Sub

Private Sub tbx_Change()  ' name of textbox is tbx
     proc_chg
End Sub

Private Sub proc_chg

    Dim rVal as Single

    rVal = Val(Me.tbx.value)

    If cbN And rVal > 0.5 Then
         tbx.BackColor = vbGreen   ' OK
    ElseIf cbH And rVal >= 0.5 Then 
         tbx.BackColor = vbGreen   ' OK
    Else
         tbx.BackColor = vbRed   ' wrong
    End If

End Sub
```

This will capture every change on the form and set the background color of the inputbox accordingly. (Please complete the logic in proc_chg, this is just an example.)